# Initializing common UI elements used in different activity in one class or activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have several EditText and TextView which are used across different layout and activity in my application and have to initialize all of them in each of the respective class. I have used `<include>` tag for the layouts.
What i am looking for is can i have a class in which i can initialize all this common views and set some desired properties and make use of this method in all the other class.

Comment: you can extend the views to custom view, and initialize them in the extension class

Comment: what i am getting from this answer is that i have to create a class which extends activity and then create classes which extends this class ?

Comment: nope, extend the TextView and EditText into CustomTextView and CustomEditText, inflate them, and initialize their parameters.

Comment: i am declaring this view in xml and then using them in android,setting the values at runtime and changing font face.but since this views are repeating in many class the code is repeating in every class. i want to write this code once in one class and then use that piece of code again in every other class.

Answer (score 1):

Craete new Class CustomTextView.java

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    Context mContext;

    public CustomTextView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
        init(context);
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);  
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(inflater != null){       
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_text_view, new LinearLayout(context));

            mContext = context;


            // set any TextView attribute here...
            this.setText("hello!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

then call new CustomTextView(this), or include it in your xml.

custom_text_view.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >    
</TextView>
```